# Paypal transactions on fresh seller account, Completed and Pending transactions

Tags: paypal

I using sandbox in my application and made some tests transactions, after each transaction i made ipn sent to my ipn controller shows that transaction status was `Pending`, but i expecting `Completed` status instead.

Then i login to my seller account to see the transactions and i saw that all transactions status was `Pending` and `Order status/Actions` was contain buttons `Accept/Reject`. Then i decided to click `Accept` in the first transaction to see what would happend next so after i click to `Accept` the first one and all the rest transactions status became `Completed`, it is heppend automatically and also i get for each of them ipn sent to my controller again (i get ipn for these transactions before but with "Pending" status), but now all ipns was with status `Completed`. it all was a big surprise for me but i was happy that i find out that.

After that, i tried to create new transaction to see what would happend and after i did that ipn sent back to my ipn controller showed that transaction status was `Completed`, so it is what i was expecting initially.

So my question is, on live environment i want the first and all the next transactions to have `Completed` status, what should i do to make it hapend? Should i configure the account somehow for that? Or should i myself send the first transaction and than click `Accept` so all the next coming transactions will be `accepted/completed` by default (the same as i accidentally done in my sendbox environment)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 'Payment review' switched on for the (first) sandbox seller account.
Go to https://developer.paypal.com/ > Test accounts and set 'Payment review' to 'Disabled'.